# python folium: how to display map change over time

Tags: folium

I am trying to follow the example given in the github of folium ([here](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/Colormaps.ipynb)). Suppose I have another csv file called `'US_Unemployment_Nov2012.csv'`. I could generate another map with color following the example's procedure. If I want to display one map, on which the color change over the time. I found some heat map with time series, but I don't know how to fit in my situation. How to implement it? Thanks!